# Parenthetical clauses with a mechanism similar to csquotes' MakeAutoQuote

Tags: macros

I have the following macro for writing parenthetical
clauses:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\incise[1]{%
    ---\,#1%
    \@ifnextchar.\relax{\@ifnextchar?{\@ifnextchar!{\@ifnextchar:{\@ifnextchar;\relax{\,---}}}}}
}
\makeatother
```

But I wanted to do the same thing that the package csquote do with quoting. It
uses active characters instead of a latex macro.

So, is it possible in LaTeX to have:

```
The main sentence -(the parenthetical clause)-.
```

transformed to:

```
The main sentence \incise{the parenthetical clause}.
```

Comment: yes and no, you could use an active character (although a command would be more normal latex syntax) but using `-` is very tricky if you do not want to break its use in lengths and other numeric values, in `--` ligatures and of course as a minus sign in math

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I didn't think about that, I should find another combination of characters. Can you give the answer anyway, I'll adapt it to the new set of characters (once I have a better idea).

Comment: @AndrewCashner csquotes has a macro MakeAutoQuote, that you can use to have the best of both worlds, semantic markup and readable source.

Comment: @AndrewCashner I find something like «text» more readable than \enquote{text}, and ---\,text\,--- more readable that \incise{text}, I used to use this second form, but I had to manage the following punctuation manually which bothered me. Once I learned about \@ifnextchar, I wrote my \incise macro. And once again I become greedy and I want the best of both worlds :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\catcode`*\active
\def*(#1)*{\incise{#1}}
```

makes `*(xxxx)*` act as you like, as long as you don't use `*` anywhere else....

Answer (score 3):

You can use the csquotes commands - they even work with utf8 chars where you can't use directly the `\catcode` trick from David. The main problem is to choose the chars so that you don't get side effects on the rest of your document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes,xcolor}

\makeatletter
\csq@addspecial{ä}{\begingroup---!ups\color{red}}{}{}%
\csq@addspecial{ö}{\endgroup!ups---}{}{}
\makeatother

 \begin{document}
 äblubö blabla 

 \end{document}
```

Comment: I settled on using "( and )" as my combination of characters. Your solution doesn't seem to work with more than one character. Also, what is !ups supposed to do?

Comment: Parentheses are used in many places -- e.g. in tikz pictures or bibliographies. So probably you will break a lot of things. Imho there are only very few good characters that you can use. Combination of characters can work: You must define the first so that it takes the next as argument or delimiter. The !ups is only there to show you that you can add arbitrary text.

Comment: I think you missed the double quote before the parenthesis.

Comment: The double quotes should work as long as you aren't using german settings (which needs the " for other things), and naturally you shouldn't try to use " to enter hexadecimal numbers.